# Sprintf Function and Character Dates

Tags: r, string, date, printf, character

I  have a data set in which I want to pad zeroes in front of a set of dates that don't have six characters. For example, I have a date that reads `91003` (October 3rd, 2009) and I want it to read `091003`, as well as any other date that is missing a zero in front.  When I use the sprintf function, the code is:

```
Data1$entrydate <- sprintf("%06d", data1$entrydate)
```

But what it spits out is something like `000127`, or some other other random number for all the other dates in the problem. I don't understand what's going on, and I would appreciate some help on the issue. Thanks.

PS. I am sometimes also getting a error message that `sprintf` is only for character values, I don't know if there is any code for numerical values.

Comment: If the data is `sprintf('%06d', c(91003,127,145))#[1] "091003" "000127" "000145"`  Please show some example data.  Are you sure that the column is numeric.

Comment: No, that whole column is just dates.  For example 100826 or 100115, but when running the previous line of code for that entire column, new data spits out 000132 or 000138 respectively.  And this is the case for all the values in the column.  And I am not sure if it is numeric since the code works sometimes.

Comment: Can you check `str(data)`.  Seems like factor column?

Comment: Yes it is a factor column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you got different results than expected because the column class was `factor`.  You can convert the column to `numeric` either by `as.numeric(as.character(datacolumn))` or `as.numeric(levels(datacolumn))`.  According to `?factor`

> To transform a factor ‘f’ to approximately its
>        original numeric values, ‘as.numeric(levels(f))[f]’ is recommended
>        and slightly more efficient than ‘as.numeric(as.character(f))’.

So, you can use

```
levels(data1$entrydate) <- sprintf('%06d', as.numeric(levels(data1$entrydate)))
```

#### Example

Here is an example that shows the problem

```
v1 <- factor(c(91003, 91104,90103))
sprintf('%06d', v1)
#[1] "000002" "000003" "000001"
```

Or, it is equivalent to

```
sprintf('%06d', as.numeric(v1)) #the formatted numbers are
# the numeric index of factor levels.
#[1] "000002" "000003" "000001"
```

When you convert it back to `numeric`, works as expected

```
sprintf('%06d', as.numeric(levels(v1)))
#[1] "090103" "091003" "091104"
```

Comment: I tried the code out and I got this error message.Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "entry_date", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 28403698

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "entry_date", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 28403698

Comment: @Adrian Could you post the `dput` output. ie. `dput(droplevels(head(data1)))`

Comment: MANAGED_ACCOUNT = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("\"N\"", 
    "\"Y\""), class = "factor"), entry_type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "11", class = "factor"), entry_rdp = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("10712", "72870"), class = "factor"), 
    entry_date = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("100512", 
 "100818"), class = "factor"), mot = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "30"), class = "factor"), import_date = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "100512"), class = "factor")

Comment: @Adrian I get error by copy/pasting the code.  Could you update it on your post

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @parkydr The OP didn't provide a dataset.  But, based on his comments, I understand that it is a factor column.  So, I posted the solution.

Comment: When I pasted the full output, I get `Error: unexpected ',' in " structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("\"N\"", "\"Y\""), class = "factor"),"`

Comment: @akrun Sorry, the review dosn't show the whole context